# questions on crontab

Tags: cron

I have following questions on cron.

1. What is the preferred way for automating cron jobs? Using *a)* crontab command-line options (eg. `crontab -e`) or *b)* editing `/etc/crontab`. What is the difference between the two? It's not exactly clear to me.
2. Is crontab user specific? If I am logged in as a a user say "anup", and add jobs using `crontab -e`, will the job be user-specific? However, in some of the cron examples I checked online, username is provided as a field between the time string and the command to be executed.
3. Can the 'Mail to user" option be controlled for each job? As in, for job 1: `MailTO: root` for job 2: `MailTO: anup`.

Answer (score 0):

1. The crontab utility is a commandline tool that maintains the crontab files for individual users.

   **crontab -l** lists/views the crontab for the current user

   **crontab -e** edits the crontab

   You can type **man crontab** for full documentation on most linux/mac systems.
2. The crontab is specific to the user. If you're logged in as anup, then crontab -e will edit anup's crontab file. You can specify the user with the -u flag (crontab -u)
3. I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that you can specify a new MAILTO= setting and it will take effect for all processes executed afterwards.